# moving with a stray cat

Tags: cats, house-moving, strays

About a year ago a sweet female cat started showing up on our patio. She took a few days to warm to us but was soon sitting in our laps and asking for pets. We were able to eventually move her indoors with our two indoor cats and she was quite happy! Unfortunately a few months ago she started regularly urinating on our couch even if we were in the room watching her, so we decided to have her go back to being an outdoor kitty. She loves being outside and regularly comes to the house for affection and food. we feed her twice a day and she’ll occasionally come into the house for a few minutes to hang out. We’re moving in about a month to a house about 12 miles away and I’m torn about what to do with her. My boyfriend is concerned that if we take her with us she won’t adjust well or she’ll run away. With the inappropriate urination it’s not really feasible for us to keep her in the house for a few weeks to start off as I’ve seen a lot of people suggest on the internet. Thoughts?

Comment: Try neutering her. Inappropriate urination mostly occurs in cats who are in heat.

Comment: Related: [Moving houses but we feed two stray cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17390/moving-houses-but-we-feed-two-stray-cats), [Adopted stray cat peeing on my bed all of a sudden](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15624/help-adopted-stray-cat-peeing-on-my-bed-all-of-a-sudden), [How can I move houses with a friendly feral cat I care for?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/how-can-i-move-houses-with-a-friendly-feral-cat-i-care-for)

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/17404/6796) as the cat will need to be taken care of, whether or not you take her.